# How does one evaluate $\lim\limits _{n\to \infty }\left(\prod_{x=2}^{n}\frac{x^3-1}{x^3+1}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I tried this form: 
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\prod_{x=2}^{n}\frac{\left(x-1\right)\left(x^2+x+1\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\left(x^2-x+1\right)}\right)$$ but it doesn't ring any bell.

Comment: Do you mean: $$\:\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\left(\prod_2^n\:\frac{\left(x-1\right)\left(x^2+x+1\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\left(x^2-x+1\right)}\right)$$ or $$\:\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\left(\prod_2^n\:\frac{\left(n-1\right)\left(n^2+n+1\right)}{\left(n+1\right)\left(n^2-n+1\right)}\right)$$ or something else

Comment: Note that: $$(x+1)^2 - (x+1) + 1 = x^2 +x +1$$

Comment: As an interesting by-product, $$\sum_{n\geq 2}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) = \frac{\log(3)-\log(2)}{2}.$$

Comment: ... from which we have the pretty tight approximation $$\zeta(3) \leq 1+\frac{\log(3)-\log(2)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write out the fraction

$\frac {(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)} $

for $x\in \{2,3,...,10\} $.  Multiply these together and note that most factors cancel; **you have a telescoping product**.  Once you figure out how the product telescopes, you can extrapolate to $n\rightarrow \infty $ and extract the terms at the "front end" of the telescope to get the limit.

Comment: And remember that two out of three ain't bad. (Subtle giveaway of the answer.)

Comment: Calculating the product till $r=10$ is time consuming.can you please provide a more shorter solution and explain how the product telescopes.thanks.

Comment: The object is to see how the factors cancel.  Once you see that the calculation isn't time consuming atxl all.